# What is different in the morning sunlight so it doesn't produce as much electricity as at noon?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, atmospheric-science, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

[image: Solar Ray depiction]

Consider I have a solar panel setup as in the above picture. The top sketch is sketching sun rays in the early morning around 6 AM in a clear bright sky. The bottom sketch is sketching the sun ray hitting the solar panel at around 8 AM.

I installed a solar panel on a mountain, where we usually see the sun more than 12 hours a day. I found that even if I turn the solar panel to face the early morning rays perpendicularly, it doesn't produce much electricity. But when it reaches around 8 AM with the solar panel to perpendicularly facing the sun, the electricity it produces will increase to almost maximum performance, not very different to the productivity at noon. Quantitatively, this is typically an increase in voltage from around 5V to 16V, of 18V maximum. In this case, it is the same sun, the same place, the same solar panel, and the same condition (it faces perpendicular to the sunray, as in the picture). So what is different in the early mornings here so that the output is so different?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When the sun is near the horizon, the sun rays have to travel through more air to get to you than when it's directly overhead.  This phenomenon is known as  *atmospheric extinction*, and [this page has a nice cartoon diagram to illustrate it:](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys445/lectures/atmos/atmos.html)

[image]

This effect can be quite large.  [This page](https://asterism.org/resources/atmospheric-extinction-and-refraction/) has a graph of the approximate effect as a function of *zenith angle*, which is the angle from directly overhead; a zenith angle of 90° is therefore an object on the horizon.

[image]

This graph is logarithmic;  every unit on the vertical axis corresponds to a factor of about 2.5 times less energy getting to the ground.  We can see that anything closer than about 15° to the horizon will have its light diminished substantially, certainly enough that you would notice on a power meter.

In addition, sunlight near the horizon is reddened substantially;  blue light is more likely to be scattered by molecules in the air, while red light is more likely to travel straight through the atmosphere to your solar panel.  (This is why sunsets are red & orange compared to the light you see during the day.)  Roughly speaking, your solar panels take particles of light (photons) and turn them into electrical energy.   But because of the properties of solar cells, there is a minimum energy that a photon must have (called the *band gap*) to excite any electricity at all.  Redder photons have less energy than bluer photons, so the red photons that are prevalent in sunlight from near the horizon may not be able to generate any electricity.*  In other words, there's a double whammy:  less photons are getting to your solar panel, and the ones that do get to your solar panel have less energy on average and can't generate electricity.

---

*I say "may not" because solar panel engineers are clever folks, and there are some more modern types of solar panel that are better at converting sunlight into electricity over a wide range of photon energies.  Look up ["multi-junction cells"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-junction_solar_cell) for more information.

Comment: Quote: **"*Sunlight near the horizon is reddened* substantially; *blue light is more likely to be scattered* by molecules in the air, while red light is more likely to travel straight through the atmosphere to your solar panel."** I think this is the answer, as I believe this is about photoelectric as this is solar panel.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I am sure it is the answer, the absent of blue light (which is high frequency). Mean, only the lower spectrum reach the solar panel.

Comment: @AirCraftLover I wonder how you can be so confident. It's definitely not obvious to me that the greater scattering of blue light has more of an effect than overall atmospheric extinction. In fact, my gut says that the latter effect is more important (bu of course I don't really know either way).

Comment: @d_b:  To be honest that would be my guess as well.

Comment: @d_b [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EkogMWJJFg) nicely explained about photoelectric effect, especially there was mentioned about red and blue light. As we know, the light comes from the sun are ROYGBIV (Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet). Red is lower frequency, means will produce less photon energy. Violet is higher energy which will produce higher photon energy. As we see the morning sun, the light is look like just red, orange, yellow. So, they will produce less photon energy. What I didn't understand previously was the scatter light due to the air molecules.

Comment: @AirCraftLover:  If you provide more details about the manufacturer & model of your solar panel, I might be able to ascertain what the band gap is and how much of an effect the reddening might have.  (No guarantees, though.)

Comment: @AirCraftLover The function for atmospheric extinction **includes** 3 factors, one of which is the "reddening" of light via Raleigh scattering(weight 0.14). The other 2 factors are aerosol scattering(weight 0.12), and molecular absorption(weight 0.02). This last one is effectively the non-transparency factor of clean air.

Comment: My guess is that the blue-light scattering is the more important contributor. As anecdotal evidence, I posit that it is pretty difficult to get sun-burned after about 4pm (at European latitudes, in summer). The sun still feels pretty warm, but you can laze by the pool for ages without any sun-burn.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, the solar panel I used is **DUNAMOS**, it is a China-made but rebranded locally in our country. So clearly I am not sure that we can find its detail technical data. I have checked the catalog, there is no such *band gap*.

Comment: @PcMan, after MichaelSeifert mentioned the scattering, I immediately realized that it was the answer. Then I searched more detail about it in Youtube. After searched, I became very sure that the scattering is the reason why less photon arrived on the solar panel surface, mean, less power generated. Yes, there are three can cause ray scatter: air molecules, water droplets, dust particles. [Here](https://youtu.be/pO7yXuk-Dgs?t=136) is the very good explanation about it.

Comment: @OscarBravo, yes, the blue and the above frequency like indigo and violet. The higher frequency, the more energy it can created. So, by the absent of the higher frequency rays, will significantly decrease the energy in the solar panel. [Here](https://youtu.be/pO7yXuk-Dgs?t=136) is a good explanation that the blue light is no more significant in the afternoon.

Comment: The band gap of silicon is 1.1 eV, which equates to 1100 nm (near IR).  So the change in the spectral distribution away from blue should have no effect—solar panels get the same energy from photons in the blue and red regions of the spectrum.  Indeed, I the small band gap explains why solar panels have low efficiency—they can't make use of most of the energy from higher-frequency visible photons.   Multi-junction panels, by contrast, whose purpose is to make better use of the higher-energy photons, would be affected by the change in the spectral distribution.

Comment: @theorist, as I mentioned, it is the same solar panel I used in the morning and noon. Mean, there is no problem with the spectrum. There must be an absent of some frequency there. And it is confirmed by Raleigh scattering.

Comment: @AirCraftLover Not following your point.  I'm saying that a standard silicon solar panel should be able to extract the same energy from a photon at the red end of the spectrum as from a photon at the blue end.  Thus the difference you are seeing in energy output is likely not due to a change in the frequency distribution from Rayleigh scattering, but rather an overall decrease in the quantity of photons due to atmospheric extinction (as Michael explained in his answer).  I.e., it's the change in the total quantity of photons hitting per unit time, not a change in their frequency distribution.

Comment: I.e., you've written this: "The higher frequency, the more energy it can created. So, by the absent of the higher frequency rays, will significantly decrease the energy in the solar panel".  But while it is true that "blue" photons are more energetic than "red" ones, a silicon solar panel can only extract a fixed amount of energy from each photon, and that fixed amount is less than the energy of even the lowest-energy red photon.   So it doesn't matter what the energy of each visible photon is -- the same amount of energy is going to be extracted from it.

Comment: @theorist:  There's a cut-off, though;  any photon with energy below the band gap is just wasted.  You could avoid this by using a really small band gap, but then you only get a small fraction of the energy from the blue photons.  So there's a trade-off between absorbing more photons and using more of the energy from the ones you do absorb. The optimal band gap (for solar panels on Earth's surface) turns out to be about 1.34 eV, which is in the near IR.  See the Wiki page on the [Shockley-Queissler limit.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley–Queisser_limit) ...

Comment: That said, some panels use multiple junctions (i.e., there are different layers with different band gaps) to more efficiently "harvest" the energy from the photons.  It's possible that if one of these band gaps is particularly large, it wouldn't be able to use "reddened" sunlight at all, and you'd take a hit to efficiency.  But I'm speculating here;  I'm not a solar-cell engineer by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your drawing, at all measurement times the sun is fully abvoe the horizon and the solar panel is always perpendicular to the line-of-sight to the sun.
In this case, what you are observing is the length of the path thru the atmosphere between "space" and the solar panel.  The atmosphere absorbs a decent amount of light per km of travel (especially at lower altitudes), leading to the lower power/m^2 received at the panel. When the sun is close to overhead, this absorption path is much shorter.

Comment: I edited the picture so I will not be misinterpreted, the solar panel is not remain on top just as like in the first sketch. As I mentioned, **it is the same place**. Everything are same except the time. Of course both situation are line of sight, it is clear, as I said, **in a clear bright sky**. As this is photoelectric effect, I believe this is must be analyzed from quantum mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

It is the earth only you should be rotating, not the ray. The reason the amount of power produced in the morning is less than that of mid day, is due to the amount of light per unit area being less in the morning. This you should see by rotating the earth only, the number of ray lines hitting your detector will decrease.

If you're tracking the ray with your solar panel, then the amount of light hitting the panel within the range that it is sensitive to diminishes due to it having to travel through a longer path in the atmosphere.

Comment: I don't think so - he says his panel is tracking, so the rays are always perpendicular to the panel, and assuming the sun is fully above his horizon, the exoatmospheric irradiance "pointing towards" the array is constant.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Ah yes, so it could be that the amount of light in the spectrum that the solar panel is sensitive to is diminished due to the extra amount of atmosphere it needs to travel through?

Comment: Quote: "*The reason the amount of power produced in the morning is less than that of mid day, is due to **the amount of light per unit area being less in the morning**.*" What is the physic explanation of this **the amount of light per unit area being less in the morning**?

Comment: Btw, I corrected the second sketch to avoid wrong interpretation. As I mentioned in my question body, **it is the same place**. So, the place are same, only different in time.